# In App Purchase Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, core-data

So I have an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)yesNo {
    int rNumber = rand() % 26;
    switch (rNumber) {
        case 0:
            result.text  = @"Never";
            break;
        case 1:
            result.text = @"If you're lucky...";
            break;
        case 3:
            result.text = @"Think twice";
            break;
        case 4:
            result.text = @"GO!";
            break;
        case 5:
            result.text = @"Hmmm. Try me again";
            break;
        case 6:
            result.text = @"As I see it, yes";
            break;
        case 7:
            result.text = @"It is certain";
            break;
        case 8:
            result.text = @"It is decidedly so";
            break;
        case 9:
            result.text = @"Most likely";
            break;
        case 10:
            result.text = @"Outlook good";
            break;
        case 11:
            result.text = @"Signs point to yes";
            break;
        case 12:
            result.text = @"Without a doubt";
            break;
        case 13:
            result.text = @"Yes";
            break;
        case 14:
            result.text = @"Yes - definitely";
            break;
        case 15:
            result.text = @"You may rely on it";
            break;
        case 16:
            result.text = @"Reply hazy, try again";
            break;
        case 17:
            result.text = @"Ask again later";
            break;
        case 18:
            result.text = @"Better not tell you now";
            break;
        case 19:
            result.text = @"Cannot predict now";
            break;
        case 20:
            result.text = @"Shake again";
            break;
        case 21:
            result.text = @"Don't count on it";
            break;
        case 22:
            result.text = @"My reply is no";
            break;
        case 23:
            result.text = @"My sources say no";
            break;
        case 24:
            result.text = @"Outlook not so good";
            break;
        case 25:
            result.text = @"Very doubtful";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

On an in app purchase, I want to replace the `result.text` values. I do not want to have to use core data, as the entire app has been written without it. Do I have to use core data?

Comment: Just stuff your text as keyed data into a plist or something.  Then just load from a different plist if the user has purchased the other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On an in app purchase, I want to
>   replace the result.text values. I do
>   not want to have to use core data, as
>   the entire app has been written
>   without it. Do I have to use core
>   data?

Why do you think you would need Core Data?

Reading between the lines, it seems like you just need a text file with one result per line.  Read the file and break it up:

```
NSString *resultsData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:...];
NSArray *results = [resultsData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
[...someController... useTheseResultsMan: results];
```

Then, your `yesNo` method would just grab the results from the array:

```
results.text = [[...someController... resultsToBeUsedMan] objectAtIndex: rNumber];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could much more easily use an NSArray read from a plist.  Create 2 new plists with all of your phrases, one with the purchased data and one with the other.

```
if (userHasPaid) {
     NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPurchasedArray" ofType:@"plist"];
} else {
     NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFreeArray" ofType:@"plist"];
}
```

Then:

```
- (IBAction)yesNo {

result.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:rNumber];

}
```

CoreData is really intended for very large data sets.  Your scenario is much, much more simple.